# Can't get text with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a problem with Selenium WebDriver in Java. When I use this code (without using `element.click();`) it works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        File salida= new File("salidas/Salida.txt");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(salida);
        PrintWriter volcado = new PrintWriter(fw);

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path to\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://ranking-empresas.eleconomista.es/REPSOL-PETROLEO.html");

        String name = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"business-profile\"]/div[17]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]")).getText();
        String obj_soc = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"business-profile\"]/div[17]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")).getText();
        String direcc = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"business-profile\"]/div[17]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]")).getText();
        String loc = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"business-profile\"]/div[17]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]")).getText();
        String tel = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"business-profile\"]/div[17]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]")).getText();
        String url = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"business-profile\"]/div[17]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[2]")).getText();
        String actividad = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"business-profile\"]/div[17]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]")).getText();

        volcado.print(name + " " + obj_soc + " " + direcc + " " + loc + " " + tel + " " + url + " " + actividad);
        volcado.close();
        driver.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But the problem came when I wanted to access by the previous page with the `element.click();` like this:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path to\\chromedriver.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://ranking-empresas.eleconomista.es/ranking_empresas_nacional.html");

    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"tabla-ranking\"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[7]/a"));
    element.click();

    String name = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"business-profile\"]/div[17]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]")).getText();
    String obj_soc = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"business-profile\"]/div[17]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")).getText();
    String direcc = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"business-profile\"]/div[17]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]")).getText();
    String loc = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"business-profile\"]/div[17]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]")).getText();
    String tel = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"business-profile\"]/div[17]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]")).getText();
    String url = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"business-profile\"]/div[17]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[2]")).getText();
    String actividad = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"business-profile\"]/div[17]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]")).getText();

    volcado.print(name+" "+obj_soc+" "+direcc+" "+loc+" "+tel+" "+url+" "+actividad);
    volcado.close();

    driver.close();
}
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}}
```

Selenium opens the browser and the pages, but my variables don’t get the text of the XPath expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is not yet present on the page at the time you are trying to get the text. Wait for the data before reading it, and it should be fine:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

driver.get("http://ranking-empresas.eleconomista.es/ranking_empresas_nacional.html");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"tabla-ranking\"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[7]/a")).click();

// Wait for the data to be present
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("business-profile")));

String name = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"business-profile\"]/div[17]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]")).getText();
String obj_soc = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"business-profile\"]/div[17]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")).getText();
String direcc = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"business-profile\"]/div[17]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]")).getText();
String loc = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"business-profile\"]/div[17]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]")).getText();
String tel = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"business-profile\"]/div[17]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]")).getText();
String url = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"business-profile\"]/div[17]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[2]")).getText();
String actividad = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"business-profile\"]/div[17]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]")).getText();

volcado.print(name + " " + obj_soc + " " + direcc + " " + loc + " " + tel + " " + url + " "+actividad);
volcado.close();
```

However, a much cleaner alternative would be to get all the cells with a single XPath expression:

```
driver.get("http://ranking-empresas.eleconomista.es/ranking_empresas_nacional.html");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"tabla-ranking\"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[7]/a")).click();

// Wait for the data to be present
List<WebElement> cells = wait.until(
  ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(
    By.xpath("//h3[.='Datos comerciales de REPSOL PETROLEO SA']/following::tbody[1]/tr/td[2]")));

String name = cells.get(0).getText();
String obj_soc = cells.get(1).getText();
String direcc = cells.get(2).getText();
String loc = cells.get(3).getText();
String tel = cells.get(4).getText();
String url = cells.get(7).getText();
String actividad = cells.get(8).getText();
```